# Why won't my PHP script compare a string to a file imported as an array?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

Here is my code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$account = "111";
$lines   = file("account.txt");
$compare = preg_replace("/#/", "", $lines); 

if ($account == $compare) {
  print("Match found!");
} else {
  print("Not found!");
}
```

The account.txt file is just a simple file that looks like this:

```
#111
222
333
```

I basically want my script to remove any # symbols from any lines in account.txt and then compare every line to the variable $account. As it is right now, it always goes to "Not Found!".

I should also mention that I want it to only do something if nothing is found for all lines, not each individual one. And if it $account is found in any of the lines, do something else.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might want to provide a sample of your account.txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) $lines is an array, but you're treating it (and the result $compare) as a single string
b) the result of file() by default includes the linebreak characters. Since `$account` does not contain such a character you want to remove them from $lines (or have file() not include them).

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$account = "111";
$lines = array_map(
    function($e) { // remove any # from all elements/lines returned by file()
        return str_replace('#','', $e);
    },
    file("account.txt",  FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES|FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
);

if ( false!==in_array($account, $lines, true) ) {
    print("Match found!");
}
else {
    print("no match");
}
```

see also: http://docs.php.net/array_map , http://docs.php.net/in_array

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I updated the original question to mention that I don't want an action done for each line. I want all lines compared first, then do an action if there was a match or not.

Comment: I removed the first solution. The seoncd (now: only) one should be a direct replacement for your code.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I'll learn from your code for future reference.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the script uses at least twice as much memory as the file size (because at some point array_map holds both the original return value of file() and the results of the str_replace-function) -> if the file gets really large you might hit the memory_limit.